# Imagens somem no Heroku após um tempo

Tags: python, django, aplicação-web, heroku, django-templates

Fiz um site para um jornal em Django. Fiz o deploy para o Heroku e lá possuo um cadastro de notícias, onde tenho os campos título, resumo, conteúdo e data.
Conforme o model:

```
class Noticia(models.Model):
    Titulo = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=False)
    Resumo = RichTextUploadingField(null=False)
    Conteudo = RichTextUploadingField(null=False)
    DataPublicacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Contudo, quando faço os cadastros as imagens somem após um tempo. O código em HTML

```
{% for noticia in noticias %}
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
                <h3 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="text-dark" href="/posts/{{ noticia.pk }}">{{ noticia.Titulo|safe }}</a>
                </h3>
                <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{ noticia.DataPublicacao|date:"d/m/y" }}</div>
                {{ noticia.Resumo|safe }}
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

A imagem está no campo Resumo, o texto que eu coloco junto com ela continua aparecendo, mas a imagem não. Estou usando o plano gratuito do Heroku, alguém sabe o que pode ser? O que pode estar causando isso?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O Heroku, gratuito ou pago, **não possui um sistema de arquivos permanente** em que você possa armazenar arquivos e/ou imagens permanentemente, como eles mesmos explicam [aqui](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted). Periodicamente o Heroku passa uma rotina interna que limpa todos os arquivos que não fazem parte do seu código rastreado pelo Git e, muito provavelmente por isso, você está vendo suas imagens serem deletadas após algum tempo.

Recomendo algum serviço de armazenamento como o AWS S3 ou o Google Cloud Storage para guardar seus arquivos.

O próprio site do Heroku tem uma [documentação oficial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python) de como implementar no S3, mas deixarei também um tutorial [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kt3ZtW9MXhw&t=4s) que considero mais didático (eu usei esse para implementar no meu site pessoal).

Comment: Muito obrigado, irei tentar implementar!